# Where in UIViewController, Controller should configure the view it manages?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit, lifecycle

I take care of it in `viewWillAppear`, but suspect there must be a better place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to configure the view is in the method `viewDidLoad` as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW25) suggests:

> You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

Also, when you create a new `UIViewController` file, the generated method literally answers your question:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both answering and listing reference